# Need to calculate the final date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008, time, calculation

[image: Date Table]

Hi All,

In the table, I have the Completed Date (2020-01-28) and I want to calculate the final date (Renewaldate) using the CompletedDate column + whatever the data in the PeriodDays, PeriodsMonths, and PeriodsYears column. For example, the completed date (2020-01-28) + 1 year in the PeriodYears table. The RenewalDate would be 2021-01-28. Any help would be appreciated

Here is my query
`SELECT  hes.CompletedDate, eve.PeriodDays, eve.PeriodMonths, eve.PeriodYears, FROM dbo.EventScheduled hes LEFT JOIN RequiredEvents eve ON hes.ID = eve.ID`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is there a column Renewaldate in any of the 2 tables and you want to update it or you just want it as a calculated column?

Comment: nope, I just want as a calculated column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CASE expression to pick the correct type of interval to add:

```
SELECT hes.CompletedDate, 
       eve.PeriodDays, eve.PeriodMonths, eve.PeriodYears,
       CASE 
         WHEN eve.PeriodDays IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(day, eve.PeriodDays, hes.CompletedDate)
         WHEN eve.PeriodMonths IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(month, eve.PeriodMonths, hes.CompletedDate)
         WHEN eve.PeriodYears IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(year, eve.PeriodYears, hes.CompletedDate)
       END Renewaldate
FROM dbo.EventScheduled hes LEFT JOIN RequiredEvents eve 
ON hes.ID = eve.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what RDBMS you use, as you'll need to use date functions. For many RDBMSes,

```
update tablename set RenewalDate = dateadd(coalesce(day, 0), PeriodDays
          dateadd(coalesce(month, 0), PeriodsMonths
            dateadd(coalesce(year, 0), PeriodsYears, CompletedDate)));
```

will work. Replace "tablename" with whatever the actual table is. You'll first have to add the new column: alter table tablename add column RenewalDate date,

Comment: thank you for your response but I don't think you get my question. Basically, I need to calculate the RenewalDate column that takes the CompleteDate column  +  whatever the data in the Days, Months, and Years column.

Comment: It's pretty much the same, just replace the select in my answer with update table name set RenewalDate =

Comment: Hi there, I updated my current query, can you help me to add your calculation into my query. I dont want to update the table in the database. Is there anyway that we can use the query for the calculation

Comment: If you don't want to update the table, then you'll need to make the select statement in my original answer.